# Split feature (MultiLine) not working as expected - newist QGIS user (version 2.18.13)

Tags: qgis

I would like to split a GPX track (saved as a SHP file multiline feature) at a specific location. The track has several incidents of overlapping line segments (double-backing on trail).
When using the "Split feature" tool, QGIS splits the track at every crisscross in addition to the desired split.  I end up with 330 features, not 2 features). This question appears to have been asked before, but not answered.  What am I doing wrong, or is there a better tool?

Comment: Can validate the geometry? Seems like there may be some invalid geometries at play